# How to increase div width according to the text inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that users input text in it. But I want to increase it's width according to it's text, until a max of 50% of the screen. My CSS code:

```
.messages {
   max-width:50%;
   min-width:150px;
   background: #ffeec0;
   padding:2px;
   margin:3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border:1px solid #ffdd7c;
}
```

Result: [image]

There's a lot of space after the "555" message, I want this size only if the user inputs some text like:

[image]

So, how can I increase the div's width dinamically, depending on the text size?

Comment: lower your min-width to say, 10em, and use display:inline-block;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, but IMHO the cleanest is the following.
Your problem is that the boxes are "greedy" and will try to expand to the available width.

To prevent this, you can:

- Make it "float: left;"
- But also "clear: left;" to prevent additional "left floating" elements to use the available space on the right.

The CSS becomes:

```
.messages {
   max-width:50%;
   min-width:150px;
   background: #ffeec0;
   padding:2px;
   margin:3px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   border:1px solid #ffdd7c;
   float:  left;
   clear: left;
}
```

I provided full code and additional explanation (on mouseover) on the Liveweave here: http://liveweave.com/DFCZFj

[image: LiveWeave screenshot]

Comment: Using float, you have to clear the float at the bottom of each block or on each next element, Take a look at this example: http://liveweave.com/KqVGPF You'd see the added paragraph wraps the floated elements. This method affects the normal flow which may cause trouble.

Comment: Is there a problem if I declare float:right? Because the messages of the user will be at the right, and the others, to the left, like Facebook, Whatsapp, etc...

Comment: float is definitely going to get you into problems if there is anything else on the page.  Except for certain special cases (wrapping text around an image), float should not be used. I've modified the liveweave posted with this answer to show you why:  http://liveweave.com/8rWIpf

Comment: Whoops.  Looks like Hashem already pointed out the problem with this solution.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `display` type of the div to `table`.

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/luseni/2/edit)**

```css
.messages {
   display: table;
   max-width: 50%;
   min-width: 150px;
   /* other declarations omitted due to brevity */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display:inline;`. You can also remove the min width property, otherwise if the text is smaller, you will still have that gap.

Comment: does inline display respect min-width?

Answer (score 2):

Block elements (`div`'s default display type) will attempt to take up the maximum horizontal space of the container.  Imagine an implicit `width:100%` whenever you see them.  `inline-block` will create block level elements in which the next element will attempt to render horizontally adjacent (provided there is enough room).  This is what you want to use (`display: table` will work in this solution as well, but it has its own idiosyncrasies.  I avoid them.

So your solution requires three parts:

First, you need to specify that the rows will be no larger than 50% of the available area.  You will do this with an outer frame:

```
.frame {
  max-width:50%;
}
```

Next, the messages themselves should each be given space entire row(s) at a time.  So we'll use an undecorated `div` tag around each message.

Finally, you will use `display: inline-block` for your innermost `messages` elements.  Since they are the only child of their parent tag, you won't have to worry about elements winding around on one another. By using the inline-block, width is respected and this gives us a great place to apply the background color.

```
.messages {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 150px;
  background: #ffeec0;
  padding:2px;
  margin:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border:1px solid #ffdd7c;  
}
```

Just as a reference, one would expect your markup will look like the following:

```
 <div class="frame">
  <div><div class="messages">2014</div></div>
  <div><div class="messages">2014</div></div>
  <div><div class="messages">
   2014-09-20 17:46:41 minhavidaemquotes:555
  </div></div>
  <div><div class="messages">
   2014-09-20 17:46:41 minhavidaemquotes:555 this is some extra
   text
  </div></div>
 </div>
```

I think you'll find this gives you the intended effect.  By the way, this is a general solution -- but if you choose a `min-width` that is larger than `50%`, you will ensure that two siblings of type `inline-block` will be too wide for a line.  If you do this, then you can dispense with the extra `div` in the markup.